# Choosing previous and next image in qt imageviewer at runtime?

Tags: image, qt, sdk

I am a noob at qt. I have been asked to develop an image viewer in qt until Wednesday. It should have the following basic functions -

Should have buttons for toggling previous and next image (among images in a folder).

Should be capable of zooming in or out

I have developed the viewer with open, zoom in and zoom out functionality.

But I still want to know how to toggle b/w images. For e.g., when clicking previous button, I should have the previous image to the one currently open in the QLabel. Similar to arrow key functionality.

I hope I am not too vague.

Answer (score 0):

Get all image file names from the image directory using QDir. Then instead of selecting the shown image using QFileDialog, select the shown image from the file name list.

Comment: U mean the user will have to input the directory, and then choose the file from the list. But that is accomplished through mouse click. I want to be able to put a menu item/ push button for it.

Comment: Also, what QDir function would I need?

Comment: How about QDir::entryList(), whose documentation says "Returns a list of the names of all the files and directories in the directory"

Comment: I need the open dialog 
this gives command line interface